# can't go back button

Tags: android

I have a problem with my Android app. I have three Activities that all connect with one another with a Image button.

My problem is I can't go back on any of the pages, just forwards. I have been reading about the back button and how to keep its state and not kill (End) it, so the user can click back if needed too.

I am new to Android and I know there's a lot to learn. So thank you for your help.

Java code for first Activity:

```
package my.hope;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.content.Intent;
public class NewhopeActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
    myImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
                Intent intent = new Intent(NewhopeActivity.this, Act2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

});
}
```

}

XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/mint">


    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imagebutton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:onClick="Act2"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you upload your manifest file ?.I can't see any problem with your code. The back button should work, as you are just goin back to the parent activity from the child activity.

Comment: android:onClick  Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked.

Comment: paste your AndroidManifest.xml too

Comment: the code that you see above is the same for all three activitys.what am thinking is that if i add a button on each page. i can code it so that all three buttons can go back a step..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you click the back button on your device? Unless specified, it kills the current activity and brings you back to the previous one.
However, if you wish to specify exactly what would clicking the back button do, you can override the onBackPressed() method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    finish();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't kill it immediately, i thought it just took it off the stack?

Comment: i dont have a button in any of my xml layouts just image button(1 on each page) if i input a button and the intent of the button and this code above it will work...thank you

Comment: Glad I could help, though I referred to the physical back button that comes with all Android devices :)